# Background Button Color Doesn't Change on_press

Tags: python, button, kivy

I am trying to make this simple script change a button's color when pressed with the on_press behavior.

Python Script: kivytest.py

```
#Import Libraries

#Import Kivy GUI
import kivy

#From kivy, import base class App
# app: always refers to instance of this application
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

################################################################################
# Creating the root widget used in the .kv file
class testLayout(StackLayout):
    pass

################################################################################

class kivytestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return testLayout()

test = kivytestApp()

test.run()
```

Corresponding .kv file: kivytest.kv

```
<StackLayout>:

    #Create the canvas
    canvas:
        #Color the canvas background a dark gray with alpha = 1
        Color:
            rgba: 0.11, 0.15, 0.17, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    #Provide the orientation of the stack layout from left to right / top to bottom
    orientation: "lr-tb"

    #Add padding between children and layout
    padding: 10

    #Add spacing between each of its children
    spacing: 5

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.2, None
        text: "second button"
        background_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]
        background_normal: ''
        on_press:
            background_color: [0, 1, 0, 1]
            print("second button pressed")
```

Unfortunately when I press the button in the app, the color remains red, but slightly darker red on_press, instead of green which I have specified. What should I correct? Is this implementation not as simple as it seems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- By just indicating background_color you are creating a variable other than the background_color property of the Button. To refer to the same object that has the scope you must use `self`.
- You should not use `:` in the assignment within an event but `=` (I think it's a bug that kivy doesn't throw an error in this case)

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
on_press:
    self.background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]
    print("second button pressed")
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for your help, I did not know that about the second error. Most tutorials I have encountered teach use of the colon rather than the equals sign. If you have any good kivy resources that you can direct me to I'd love to read them or look into them.

Comment: @Xonu Notice where it is used, within the on_X you should use python code and not kivy code. Unfortunately, the only recommendation I make is to review the docs since I don't use another resource.